# How to List All Redis tables?

Tags: python, redis-cluster

Using Redis Python library, how can we list all the tables that exist in a redis cluster?
I tried `REDIS.info()` but it doesnt give the tables I have in the cluster!

Comment: Redis does not have a concept of a table. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: trying a pyspark code that connect to redis, I only tried to retreive soome keys based on the pattern with no table option but it didn't work. this is the error `pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException: Option 'table' is not set.`